# Garbage values when array declared as unsigned char

Tags: c++, type-conversion, unsigned, unsigned-char

When an array is declared as unsigned char and initialized with values in the range 0x00-0xff and printed using cout, I get garbage values as follows

```
+   (   �           
~   �   �   �   
    �       O   
    �   �   <
```

May I know how to use use single byte for the numbers and yet be able to use cout ?

Comment: can we see both the initialization code and the printing code?

Comment: You're trying to print non-printable characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's an `unsigned char`, `std::cout` is passing them to the terminal and it's being displayed as a character set (Well, attempting, anyway - the values are outside the range of valid printable characters for the character set you're using).

Cast to `unsigned int` when outputting with `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

Char types are displayed as characters by default. If you want them displayed as integers, you will have to convert them first:

```
unsigned char value = 42;
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't garbage values.  Those are what the character represents.  To print it as an int, simply cast to `unsigned int` at output time:

```
cout << (unsigned int) some_char;
```